# assign css properties with spread operator in styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm making react component with material-UI and styled-components in TypeScript. 
While implementing [Drawer like this](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer), I have trouble passing css properties to styled components with spread operator.

Originally, it's implemented with useStyles like this;

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
createStyles({
    drawerHeader: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      }, 
}),
);

const SideDrawerHeader: React.FC = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to write those codes with styled-components, without useStyles. 
Currently, my codes are like below, but they don't work well. 
I might mistakenly use `attr`, however I have no idea how to pass css properties with spread operator in styled-components.

```
 const SideDrawerHeader: React.FC = (props) => {
    return (
        <$DrawerHeader>
            {props.children}
        </$DrawerHeader>
    );
}

const $DrawerHeader = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
 // this css properties don't seem assigned
     ...props.theme.mixins.toolbar,
 }))`
 /* the part below works fine */
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     padding: ${props => props.theme.spacing(0, 1)};
     justify-content: flex-end;
`;
```

I referred to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210171/using-the-spread-operator-in-styled-components), but it didn't work for my case. 
Can anyone show me clue? Thank you.